# How to assign random int to long int dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++

To make a method for filling dynamically assigned array with random numbers, I used following method:

```
void autoFill(long int *fillArr[], int length) {
    srand(1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        fillArr[i] = rand();
    }
}
```

However, `fillArr[i] = rand();` doesn't work because this line tries to convert `int` to `long *`. How do I assign this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why is it `long int *fillArr[]` instead of `long int fillArr[]` ?

Comment: `*(fillArr[i]) = rand();` instead of `fillArr[i] = rand();`

Comment: Side note: `rand()` is outdated, use `<random>` lib instead

Comment: @ScottHunter Visual studio gives an error: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "long *"

Comment: @drescherjm, I need a dynamically assignrd array

Comment: `long int fillAry*` would be fine for a 1D array that was dynamically allocated with `new`

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian that seems to work, thanks. Though, now it demands an expression within [] when function is called, but that's a different problem anyway

Comment: `long int *fillArr[]` is an array of "dynamically allocated array", i.e jagged 2D array, not a 1D array at all

Comment: @Dan2004 Let's see how you are calling this function.  Having a `long int *fillArr[]` doesn't make sense, given what you have written.  It makes more sense to have `long int *fillArr`.

Comment: @Dan2004 No its not. The problem is that `long int *fillArr[]` should be `long int fillArr[]` or `long int* fillArr`.Your error is thinking that you needed to make `fillArr` a pointer and an array, when it should just be a pointer. How to pass arrays to a function is covered in any C++ book or tutorial.

Comment: A side issue, but this use of `srand` is not going to get you any random numbers.

Comment: @john All of that requires constant value

Comment: @Dan2004 I'm not really sure what you are referring to. If you mean that you understand you are going to get the same 'random' numbers each time you run your program, then you are correct, and I guess everything is fine.

Comment: @phuclv — `long int *fillArr[]` as a function argument is a pointer to a pointer. It says nothing about the structure, if any, of the object that the pointer points at. Yes, you could pass an array of pointers, and those pointers might point at dynamically allocated arrays of various sizes, but there’s no way to know any of that from the type declaration.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know. That's why I put the thing inside brackets as it's what the OP likely expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an 1D array that stores long int, you pass the argument in the wrong way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctime>

void auto_fill(long int *arr, int length) {
    srand(1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr [i]=rand();
    }
}

int main()
{
    long int *myarray;
    int length=20;
    myarray = new long int[length];
    auto_fill(myarray, length);
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
        std::cout << myarray [i]<<std::endl;
}
```

please note that rand() return a int, not a long int

Comment: Tactical notes for future askers: 1) Reach for `new` only after you have eliminated `std::vector`, every other library container, `std::make_unique`, and `std::make_shared`. This should be extremely rare. 2) Only call `srand` once, typically near the top of `main`, because every time you call it it restarts the number generator and you'll get the same sequence over again.

Comment: `#include <algorithm> void auto_fill((long int *arr, int length) { std::generate_n(arr, length, [](){ return rand(); });}`

Comment: this leaks memory and isn't a good practice at all

Answer (score -3):

Looks like I had to write `*(fillArr[i]) = rand();` instead of `fillArr[i] = rand();`
Now there is another problem, though.

Comment: No that change is not correct. I can only think that the compile time comedian was having a little joke with you.

Comment: Four people now have told you the correct answer, but unfortunately you went with the wrong one.

Comment: @john — you don’t know what that pointer points at. I  agree that this **probably** isn’t the right thing, but it’s certainly possible that it’s correct.

Comment: More context in both question and answer necessary to tell whether or not this is a correct answer. Unfortunately that also makes this answer not particularly useable.